# Testimonial through loop

Tags: jquery, wordpress, testimonials

I have created testimonials through loop

I want when a user clicks here (see the image) it shows one testimonial and hides the other

[image]

My code:

```
                <h1>TESTIMONAIL</h1> 
                <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array(
                            'post_type'  => 'testimonial',
                            'orderby'    => 'post_id',
                            'order'      => 'ASC'
                            ));?>

                    <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop ->the_post(); ?>                 
                    <div class="client active">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail () ) {
                                the_post_thumbnail();
                            } ?>
                        </div> <!-- Col -->
                        <div class="col-sm-6 testi-name">
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            <h5><?php echo $his_her_job; ?></h5>

                        </div> <!-- Col -->
                        <p class="lead"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                                                        <?php endwhile; 
                        wp_reset_query();
                        ?>
                    </div> <!-- Client -->
                </div> <!-- Row -->
                <p class="lead"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="next float-right">Next Testimonial <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></div>
                    <div class="next float-left"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous Testimonial</div>
```

How can i use jquery to achieve this?

Comment: use owl-carousel, please check the documentation

Comment: Yes you need a carousel for this. Owl Carousel https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/ is best for creating carousels